# Restore drag and drope positions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I use drag and drope jquery ui in my code. And the code works fine. But user should have some ability to edit data after saving. It means that I need to restore drag and drope positions when user opens the page again. I try to use trigger but I can't emulate "drop ui" How can I do it?

```
$( ".draggable-children-username" ).draggable({
    snap: ".draggable-in-box",
    opacity: 0.7,
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: "clone"
});
$(".draggable-in-box").droppable({
    accept: $(".draggable-children-username"),
    hoverClass: "dropHover",
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
        $(this).trigger("DopeEvent", ui);
    }
});

$( ".draggable-in-box" ).bind("DopeEvent", function(event, ui ){
    console.log(ui);

    var me = ui.draggable.clone()
    ui.draggable.draggable("disable")
    me.appendTo(this)
    .addClass("newClass");
    me.draggable({
        accept: ".draggable-in-box",
        revert: function(valid) {
            if(!valid) {
                this.remove();
                $(".dr-children-id-"+this.attr("data-id")).draggable("enable");
            }
        }
    });
});

$( ".draggable-in-box" ).trigger("DopeEvent", $( ".dr-children-id-140" ));
```

Current error: Uncaught TypeError: ui.draggable.clone is not a function

http://jsfiddle.net/vjGY4/123/

Comment: I am unable to replicate the issue you are describing.

Comment: @Twisty draggable ("Element" in my example jsfiddle) should be automatically drop to box when you open the page. (without drag and drop by hand)

Comment: So you want to perform an animation of it moving into the box?

Comment: Also, in your binding, you're simply receiving  a element. so when you call `ui.draggable`, it is not a `draggable()`. I would suggest just using `$(ui).clone();` instead of `ui.draggable.clone()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few fixes. Working example of what I think you're trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vjGY4/125/

**JQuery**

```
$(".draggable-children-username").draggable({
  snap: ".draggable-in-box",
  opacity: 0.7,
  revert: 'invalid',
  helper: "clone"
});

$(".draggable-in-box").droppable({
  accept: $(".draggable-children-username"),
  hoverClass: "dropHover",
  drop: function(ev, ui) {
    $(this).trigger("DopeEvent", ui.draggable);
  }
});

$(".draggable-in-box").bind("DopeEvent", function(event, ui) {
  console.log(ui);

  var me = $(ui).clone();
  //ui.draggable.draggable("disable")
  me.appendTo(this)
    .addClass("newClass");
  me.draggable({
    accept: ".draggable-in-box",
    revert: function(valid) {
      if (!valid) {
        this.remove();
        $(".dr-children-id-" + this.attr("data-id")).draggable("enable");
      }
    }
  });
});

$(".draggable-in-box").trigger("DopeEvent", $(".dr-children-id-140"));
```

1. Do not assume you're being passed a draggable object or a jquery object in you `DopeEvent`. Use `var me = $(ui).clone();`
2. In your `drop`, you need to pass the element like so: `$(this).trigger("DopeEvent", ui.draggable);`

Hope that helps. You could improve your event by checking what is being passed. Something like `if(typeof ui === "object"){}` could work.